# Simplifying ASP.Net MVC Razor Code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looking for suggestions on how to simplify/optimize a piece of code in one of my view files in my ASP.Net MVC project. The code works, but I'm not sure if I've written it the best way.

Basically, the code is used to display a list of links to documents, with little thumbnails to the left of each link. The main problem, is that there are two different types of documents, and each type has to have it's thumbnail image stored in a different location, this is a project requirement and can't be changed.

I'm currently accomplishing this with the view code shown below.

```
// Display a link to every document.
foreach (var document in documentList)
{
    <a href="@Url.Content("~/Document/DownloadDocument/" +
        document.documentid)" target="_blank">
    @{
        // This will be the root of all the paths.
        var path = "~/Document/DisplayImage/";

        // If it's a Type 1 document, we need to use a different path.
        if (document.documentType == "Type 1") {
            path += "Path/To/Image/Folder";

            <img id="imageHolder" src="@Url.Content(path)"
                 onerror="imgError(this);" />
            @document.documentname
        }
        else {
            path += "Path/To/Different/Image/Folder";

            <img src="@Url.Content(path)" />
            @document.documentname
        }
    }
    </a>
    <br />
}
```

Like I said, the code works, but I'm not too happy with how it's written. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with MVC, it's best to keep your Views dumb (no logic, simply rendering).

You can accomplish this by using a strongly-typed View and performing all of the logic in the Controller. It looks like you may already be doing this since you have a `documentList`.

In this case, `documentList` should be a list of View Model objects that already have the appropriate image path already set on them from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the path to your document image into your model. That way you can just display the image from the path in the model and you wouldn't have to put any logic in your view.